# Magento - No price in product page

Tags: magento

I have SCP (simple configurable product) installed and for every simple product that has no custom options, the price doesn’t show up in the product page. As soon as I add an option, the price shows up.

There is no price block or template called on the product page when no options is selected.

I saw that the extension is extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price block , but I can't find where this block should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't found any solution yet , so I made this jquery workaround that works

Put this at the end of template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     if($('.price-box').length==0){
         var price = '<div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price"><span class="price">$<?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(),2); ?></span></span></div>';
         $('.product-options-bottom').before(price);
     }
 });
```

Of course, you need to have jquery.

Comment: Thanks - how you add jQuery?